# How to change UISlider background color with slide

Tags: iphone, ios, uislider, uicolor

I want to change UISlider background color with slide like this

[image]

I have tried this code but it is not like this type view

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *r;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *g;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *b;

-(void)blueSlider:(UISlider*)slider {
    UIColor *newColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:_r.value green:_g.value blue:_b.value alpha:1];
   _b.backgroundColor=newColor;
}

-(void)greenSlider:(UISlider*)slider {
    UIColor *newColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:_r.value green:_g.value blue:_b.value alpha:1];
    _g.backgroundColor=newColor;
}

-(void)redSlider:(UISlider*)slider  {
    UIColor *newColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:_r.value green:_g.value blue:_b.value alpha:1];
   _r.backgroundColor=newColor;
}
```

I want particular this look.

Comment: So you want a gradient behind each slider?

Comment: Check the links provided in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in header file import quartzCore and define layer instances as

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    CAGradientLayer *red_gradient;
    CAGradientLayer *green_gradient;
    CAGradientLayer *blue_gradient;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *r;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *g;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *b;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *colorLabel;
-(IBAction)sliderValue:(UISlider*)sender;
@end
```

In implementation file initialize layers and set frames of UISliders as given below

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    red_gradient =[CAGradientLayer layer];
    green_gradient =[CAGradientLayer layer];
    blue_gradient=[CAGradientLayer layer];

    CGRect rect=_r.frame;
    rect.size.height=10;
    [_r setFrame:rect];

    rect=_g.frame;
    rect.size.height=10;
    [_g setFrame:rect];

    rect=_b.frame;
    rect.size.height=10;
    [_b setFrame:rect];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

In view did appear method call addLayers method as

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self addLayers];
}
```

On value change slider method call addSubLayers method as

```
-(IBAction)sliderValue:(UISlider*)sender
{
    [self addLayers];
    UIColor *newColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:_r.value green:_g.value blue:_b.value alpha:1];
   _colorLabel.backgroundColor = newColor;
}
```

And At last here is your addLayers Method :---

```
-(void)addLayers
{
    UIColor *startColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:_g.value blue:_b.value alpha:1];
    UIColor *endColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:_g.value blue:_b.value alpha:1];

    red_gradient.frame = _r.bounds;
    red_gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[startColor CGColor], (id)[endColor CGColor], nil];

    [red_gradient setStartPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.5)];
    [red_gradient setEndPoint:CGPointMake(1.0, 0.5)];

    [_r.layer insertSublayer:red_gradient atIndex:2];

    startColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:_r.value green:0 blue:_b.value alpha:1];
    endColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:_r.value green:1 blue:_b.value alpha:1];

    green_gradient.frame = _g.bounds;
    green_gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[startColor CGColor], (id)[endColor CGColor], nil];

    [green_gradient setStartPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.5)];
    [green_gradient setEndPoint:CGPointMake(1.0, 0.5)];

    [_g.layer insertSublayer:green_gradient atIndex:2];

    startColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:_r.value green:_g.value blue:0 alpha:1];
    endColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:_r.value green:_g.value blue:1 alpha:1];

    blue_gradient.frame = _b.bounds;
    blue_gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[startColor CGColor], (id)[endColor CGColor], nil];

    [blue_gradient setStartPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.5)];
    [blue_gradient setEndPoint:CGPointMake(1.0, 0.5)];

    [_b.layer insertSublayer:blue_gradient atIndex:2];
}
```

it would look like :--------

[image]

Comment: Anyone got this to work on Swift 2.0, Xcode 7? I'm not able to change the frame of the slider, and I'm not able to change the color ether.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not achieve the desired look because you are setting the background color of the slider all together.

Take a look at the [CGGradient reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CGGradient/Reference/reference.html) to learn how to use gradients.

Also, what you pictured is not looking like a slider at all, but rather like an object within the bounds of a gradient that changes the value through a `panGestureRecognizer`.

To learn about that, [visit the UIPanGestureRecognizer Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPanGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html)